# Dependency injection in constructor - type hinting not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
<?php
namespace Http\Models;

class DbModel {
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct( \Ilib\Database\Database $dbh ) { 
        $this->dbh = $dbh;     
    }

    public function select(){
        $this->dbh->query( "SELECT * from prednasky ORDER by mesic ASC" );  }
    } 
}
```

I see error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Http\Models\DbModel::__construct() must be an instance of Ilib\Database\Database, none given, where Ilib\Database\Database is the connection into the pdo db.
```

But my question is, where can I create a new instance? and how its look this instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
$database = new \Ilib\Database\Database();
$model = new DbModel($database);
```